# How to bypass PowerPoint 2007 PresendationBeforeSave

Tags: office-interop, powerpoint-2007

I'm having some problems with bypassing the Application_PresentationBeforeSave event in MS Office PowerPoint 2007

void Application_PresentationBeforeSave(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation Pres, ref bool Cancel)

In this event, I need to update a webservice, with the byte[] content of the file.
But at this point in time, the file is not saved. There is no event called PresentationAfterSave fx that is called.

I need some way of calling the event again, after it is saved.
Some people are saying that I need to make a Thread, due the save and then the update or the otherway around. This is by far the worst solution (but properly the only one), is there a better solution ?

// dennis

Comment: Have you tried PresentationSave rather than PresentationBeforeSave?

Comment: Thx, that did the trick. I dont know why I did see that event :S
Can you provide an answar, so I can close this question.

Comment: An answer to why you didn't see the event?  Can't help with that.  I'm looking at events in the object browser in PPT's VBA IDE.

Comment: You need to add your answar by pushing the "Answar you question" at the bottom of the page :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PresentationSave rather than PresentationBeforeSave event is what you're looking for, I think.